# How to display bullet points with variable length in Android that are underneath each other

Tags: java, android, textview, popupwindow

I would like to add a list with bullet points with variable size (line numbers) in an Android popup window (with Java) such that the bullets starts directly underneath each other. For example I have the list

- First Information line
- Second information line that constains more text and can't be displayed in one line in the App
- Third information line

The bullet points come from a database query. Now how can I implement this? I tought about using a textView for every bullet point. The bullet points are the columns of a database query (so I have multipel columns per row with the text; each of them has 1 bullet point). The problem is that if I specify the textView in the XML layout file, I can't know in advance how many line it should cover and thus I can't position the textViews correctly.
Another approach might be to just use 1 column in the database for all bullets but use some formatting symbols in the string and try to build the string using the formating symbols just in 1 TextView. As I have no experience with such a approach I just wanted to ask you, what other ways (possibly more convenient) exist to do something like this?

I'd appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I dont understand 100% what situation you're trying to describe, I dont know why you stored bullet in your database? However, if you want to build the bullet points with texts dynamically, you can refer to this [article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1yIzo8pnwAhVI_GEKHe8OANEQFjAAegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fandroiddevelopers%2Funderspanding-spans-1b91008b97e4&usg=AOvVaw3CndSGUZvCFGT2dn6A8VZ9) for more information

Comment: Thanks Phuc for your answer. Basically the idea with the bullet points in the database (or some other) symbol was just an option that I have thought about. I do not have bullet points in the database at the moment. What I want is to have bullet points in textviews such that they are underneath each other. I am wondering how to specify this in the XML layout files as I can't know in advance how many line it should cover and thus I can't position the textViews correctly

Comment: As I said, you can dynamically set the bullet points based on my reference link. If you dont know how many line it would take, just modify the layout so that, for example, it may scroll if your TextView containing the bullet has many lines.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thanks for your answer Phuc. I upvoted and accepted it.